# ошибка: "Дескриптор SafeHandle был закрыт (mscorlib.pdb не загружен)"

Tags: c#

Я удаляю и создаю соответствующую переменную закрытого устройства и пытаюсь подключить это устройство через COM-порт заново с помощью функции `Open()` при отключенном самом устройстве соответственно (попыток делается очень много раз, пока устройство не подключается).

И у меня возникает ошибка с такой трассировкой:

> в System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
>      в System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
>      в Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(SafeFileHandle hFile, NativeOverlapped* lpOverlapped, Int32& lpNumberOfBytesTransferred, Boolean bWait)
>      в System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommEvent()
>      в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Дело в том что я уже пробовал запускать и так и запускать с помощью `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...` и ничего всё равно не получается.

Исключение вылетает асистематически через раз.

Здесь имя порта указывается из настроек по умолчанию программы, порт COM сам не закрывается, а лишь пересоздаётся переменная которая с ним работает, само устройство не подключено к порту и при каждой попытке (а их много) функция Open() не срабатывает, но программа все равно вылетает, прямо дойдя только до этой функции Open(). Саму библиотеку работы с устройством мне отослать здесь не удалось:

```cs
private void billAcceptorConnect()
{
   try
   {
       billAcceptor = new CashCodeSm();
       billAcceptor.PortName = Properties.Settings.Default.ComPort;
       billAcceptor.Open();
       billAcceptor.IsAcceptanceEnabled = false;
       billAcceptor.BillsOnEscrow += billAcceptor_BillsOnEscrow;
       billAcceptor.BillsStacked += billAcceptor_BillsStacked;
       billAcceptor.CashBoxRemoved += billAcceptor_CashBoxRemoved;
       billAcceptor.BillsRejected += billAcceptor_BillsRejected;
       billAcceptor.BillsReturned += billAcceptor_BillsReturned;
       billAcceptor.CashBoxAttached += billAcceptor_CashBoxAttached;
       billAcceptor.CashBoxIsAlmostFull += billAcceptor_CashBoxIsAlmostFull;
       billAcceptor.CashBoxIsFull += billAcceptor_CashBoxIsFull;
       billAcceptor.Error += billAceptor_Error;
    }
    catch
    {
         billAcceptor = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Эээ... Ошибка _загрузки mscorlib_? Очень странно, без mscorlib программа вовсе не должна запускаться.

Comment: Попробуйте составить воспроизводящий минимальный пример. Без него непонятно, в чём может быть проблема.